# Mobx: destructing observable properties for to local scope

Tags: typescript, mobx, destructuring

I just inherited some code that has some conventions I'm a little concerned about.  It's using mobx for state management (which I've never used before), and I had a question about something I keep seeing over and over:

The previous author like to destructure all his observable state to local variable before using them:

```
@observer
class FooForm extends React.Component {
    @observable
    public fooString: string;
    @observable
    public fooNum: number;
    @observable
    public error: string;

    @action public submitFoo = () => {
        let {fooString, fooNum} = this; //for brevity?

        if(!fooString.length){
           this.error = 'Foo String must be set';
           return;
        }
        if(!fooNum < 100){
           this.error = 'fooNum must be at least 100';
           this.fooNum = 100;
           return;
        }
        //...submit
    }
    // render() and such...
}
```

It seems like they did this just to try and shorten their code (EG `fooNum` vs `this.fooNum`), however in doing so, it feels like they have polluted the local scope with references that are likely to introduce bugs, given the requirements around observables.

EG: it would be very easy to accidentally type `fooNum = 100;` instead of `this.fooNum = 100;` which would not trigger an observable state change!

The [mobx common pitfalls doc](https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html) does warn against storing observables locally, but this is a little different since they are just being declared in the local scope.

Am I overreacting? Is this actually common practice in mobx apps?

Or am I justified to bring it up with them?  (like I said, I'm brand new to mobx so I don't know what is the norm).

Comment: Also, is it just me, or does it feel dirty to put the observables directly on the react component?  Seems like at the very least they should be put into their own "Store" class

Comment: looking at the code a little more, they are using `const` instead of `let` like my example show... I guess that would prevent the accidentally assignment

Comment: This particular example, to me, looks like over-use of MobX.  If these are local to this component, you may as well be using native React state management, IMHO.  I prefer to reserve MobX usage for when state needs to be shared and pass it in via a React component's props

Comment: I definitely agree with that statement... react state would have been more than sufficient for this app